# Google complains of Error: "Missing XML tag" while using Xmap in Joomla2.5

Tags: xml, url, joomla2.5

My sitemap (generated automatically by Xmap in Joomla 2.5) is simply the following:

```
<urlset xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd"></urlset>
```

It's successfully checked and well-formed XML, with 3 warnings  in 'validator.w3.org'.

However, Google didn't accept it, so I had to add the following line in front of it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

While it was accepted, Google flags for an error; "Missing XML tag".

What is the solution?

Comment: I indented the code in you post to make it visible. I left the formatting as close as possible to what you posted originally cause I think it may be significant. Notice that you've got two URLs joined in the value of `xsi:schemaLocation`. Is this a typographical error or perhaps the cause of your problem?

Comment: You made a good point; it seems strange.

Comment: But this code is created automaticcaly by Joomal! I tested it exactly as it is in "validator.w3.org" and it was ok. You can test it yourself. I paste the original code (copied from notepad)again: <urlset xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd"></urlset>

Answer (score 0):

If your XML Sitemap has less than 50,000 URLs and is less than 10MB in size then you do not need to use Sitemap Indexes.
Check protocol [here](http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html).

Another try you can do is: simply unchecked All "Post Types" under "Post Types" and then check only Posts and Pages.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't know what you are referring to by 'All "Post Types" under "Post Types"'. Where, in Joomla?                                         P.S. It's completely a DIFFERENT question, by the way: I don't visit this site so often. In order to see my questions and answers, I have to search after title of my 'question'. Is there any easier way to do that? Thanks.

Comment: @AbeEkbatani You can always visit to this Link(Its your profile) http://stackoverflow.com/users/780895/abe-ekbatani At bottom you can see the question what you have asked and just click on that.